# Observing a value of a static var in a class?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing, class-variables

I have a class with a `static var` where the current online connection status is stored. I want to observe the value of `ConnectionManager.online` through other classes. I wanted to do this with *KVO*, but declaring a `static` variable as `dynamic` causes an error:

```
class ConnectionManager: NSObject {
    dynamic static var online = false
    // adding 'dynamic' declaration causes error:
    // "A declaration cannot be both 'final' and 'dynamic'
}
```

What is a most elegant way of doing this?

**Update**. This my code for the KVO part:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ConnectionManager.addObserver(
        self,
        forKeyPath: "online",
        options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(),
        context: nil
    )
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, 
                                     ofObject object: AnyObject?, 
                                     change: [String : AnyObject]?, 
                                     context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "online" {
        print("online status changed to: \(ConnectionManager.online)")
        // doesn't get printed on value changes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for now, Swift cannot have observable class properties. (In fact, static properties are just global variables with its namespace confined in a class.)

If you want to use KVO, create a shared instance (singleton class) which has `online` property and add observer to the instance.

Comment: Thanks, will try the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it with the `singleton` pattern suggested by @OOper.

```
class ConnectionManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = ConnectionManager()
    private override init() {} // This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.
    @objc dynamic var online = false
}
```

Then:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.addObserver(self,
                         forKeyPath: "online",
                         options: [.new, .initial],
                         context: nil)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if object is ConnectionManager && keyPath == "online" {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: added `@objc` per the errors here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419893/nsunknownkeyexception-was-sent-to-an-object-that-is-not-kvc-compliant-for-the

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `dynamic static var online = false` to `@nonobjc static var online = false`

What's happening is that because it inherits from NSObject, Swift is trying to generate getters and setters for it. Because you are creating it in swift, using the @nonobjc attribute solves the problem.

**EDIT:**

I don't believe you can observe static variables through KVO because of how it works

Here is a link and snippet from  [Apple's Guide on KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

> Unlike notifications that use NSNotificationCenter, there is no
>   central object that provides change notification for all observers.
>   Instead, notifications are sent directly to the observing objects when
>   changes are made.

Perhaps, instead of using KVO, you could declare online like:

```
static var online = false {
    didSet{
        //code to post notification through regular notification center
    }
}
```

If you're set on using it, this question might point you towards the right direction — it'll involve diving deeper into how KVO works:  [Is it possible to set up KVO notifications for static variables in objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413110/is-it-possible-to-set-up-kvo-notifications-for-static-variables-in-objective-c)

Comment: @MJQZ1347 Updated answer

Comment: I also thought of `NSNotification` but I am kind of surprised that there is no other way to observe static vars. But I think it is the way to go then. Also: Why not use `didSet` instead of `set`?

Comment: @MJQZ1347 Whoops, my bad. I meant `didSet`. You're right, though, that is kind of strange as it's a pretty useful feature. Maybe it'll come in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest property wrapper, I tried the example below and worked perfectly for me:

```
    @propertyWrapper
    struct StaticObserver<T> {
        private var value:T
        init(value:T) {
            self.value = value
        }
        var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            // Do your thing
            return self.value
        }
        set {
            // Do your thing before set 
            self.value = newValue
            // Do your thing after set
        }
    }

    @StaticObserver(value: false)
    dynamic static var online:Bool
```