# NSUnknownKeyException : was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "player" property

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9, kvc

I have updated my code to swift 4 in Xcode 9. Before that it was working fine. But now AVplayer is crashing at observers below is the code where it is crashing.

```
addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "player.currentItem.duration", options: [.new, .initial], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
```

And the log is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSUnknownKeyException',reason: '[ addObserver: forKeyPath:@"player.currentItem.duration" options:5
>   context:0x10ff74ac8] was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant
>   for the "player" property.'

Comment: Thanks Tushar Sharma for the edit

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Swift does not have the Key value observer of its own so for Swift 4 we have to add:

`@objc dynamic`

before the property whose value you need to observe. In your case it will be the AVPlayer instance. e.g.:

```
class MyPlayerCustomView: UIView {

@objc dynamic var myPlayer: AVPlayer?

}
```

Hope this solves your problem. It did solve mine!

Comment: As an explanation, dynamic makes the property to be dispatched by the Objective-C runtime. That's why @objc is needed too.